# How to pass variable from Activity to Adapter

Tags: java, android

I need to pass a variable from an Activity to a GridView Adapter. What I tried was:

Declaring a method inside the activity:

```
public int getPoints()
{
    return points;
}
```

The in the adapter I declared:

```
mainActivity sel= new mainActivity();
```

And finally I called the method using:

```
int myPoints = sel.getPoints();
```

But it always returns 0. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: why you are declaring activity instance inside adapter? Search for a good tutorial first.

Comment: This is not the way to call method from activity. you need context

Comment: @EagleEye can you explain me why is it a wrong approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add argument to your adapter constructor
2. Pass your variable when instantiating adapter `MyGridAdapter adapter = new MyGridAdapter(myVariable)`

To update variable from your activity you can also create method in your adapter and call it adapter.updateMyVariable(newVariable);

Comment: Since I get the variable during the Activity I tried to create the method inside the adapter and call it from the activity but I get this error:
Attempt to invoke virtual method (...) on a null object reference

Comment: Try to debug and check why your adapter instance is null. Did you created new instance before trying to call this method?

Comment: yeah I just fixed it, I was calling the method before initializing the adapter, ty this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Create public static variable points in mainActivity and then call from adapter mainActivity.points.